# Why "Dropdown" not working (with codes)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

First Laravel Project.

The "built-in" app.blade.php (what made when we run `php artisan make:auth`) has this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('main')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My master.blade.php has this code (I copied some from the app.blade.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html class="html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="media/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php Debugbar::info('Mesterkész'); ?>
        <header>
            <h1>@yield('title')</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
            <section class="navbar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav></section>
            <section class="nav">
                <table align=center border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/"><button class=button>Főoldal</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/inventory"><button class=button>Leltár</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/sell"><button class=button>Eladási mód</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/supplier"><button class=button>Beszállítók</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/search"><button class=button>Keresés</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/stats"><button class=button>Statisztikák</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/options"><button class=button>Beállítások</button></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/log"><button class=button>Naplózás</button></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        @section('submenu')
                        @show
                        @yield('content')
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </section>
            <section class="main">
                @section('main')
                @show
                @yield('content')
            </section>
        </article>
    </body>
    <footer id=footer>
    //Footer will go there

</footer>
</html>
```

My question is: Why the Dropdowns are working in the app.blade.php and not in master.blade.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered, but than deleted somewhy his answer.
The problem was, that I forgot to copy this part:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: you are my hero